# How to append an image in div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, oop

I have a list of small images while clicking on each of them they should show up in the div(the idea is to see them bigger)

I have used append function jQuery but it does not work

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.selectable a img').click(function() {
    var img=$(this).attr('src');    
    alert(img);// this is what i get  data/100.jpg but it does not show up in div
    ('#div1').append('img');
  });

});
```

part of CSS Code:

```
 <ul> 
    <?php foreach ($cakeTypeService->getByTypeAndSubtype('stage', 'ROSE') as $cake) { ?>
     <li class="selectable" id="cakeType-<?= $cake->id ?>">
       <a href="?cakeType=<?php echo ($cake->id); ?>" title="Selecteer">
       <?php if ($cake == $order->cakeType){?><span class="checked"></span><?php } ?>
       <img src="data/<? echo $cake->id ?>.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></a>                                 
      </li>
     <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried ?

```
$(function() {
    $('a img').click(function() {
    $img=$(this).attr('src');    

    $('#div1').append("<img src="+$img+" />")

  });

});
```

Comment: your example somehow helped me but if i alert ($('#div1').append('<img src="' + img + '" />') );then i get [object object] does not show the img insede the div

Comment: @Mary because its an object. What do you want to get from alert ? If you want the html code inside of the #div1, you should do alert($('#div1').html());

Comment: hey Baris wait dont go see my img shows only for a minute iside the div then gets lost therefore i have this code $("#div1 img:last-child").remove() ; before append fun but it does not work plz help

Comment: @Mary Please let me know exactly what are you trying to do ? I dont understand what you mean above

Comment: The image you clicked is dissappears or the image inside the div is disapprears ? Actually I run your code but nothing happens sth one of these. What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

I know your question specifically asked for how to manually achieve this but there are existing plugins out there that would do the bulk of this work for you:

[A great example here](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery).

[Another example here](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/imgPreview/full/).

You could use this plugin or at least use it for inspiration to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

you can see this live demo right here
http://jsfiddle.net/chhameed/nWqcv/

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a $ (here ('#div1'))  and doing some weird things with what you append (actually you are trying to append a collecttion of all images on the page. (selected with $('img');

try this:

```
$(function() { 
$('.selectable a img').click(function() { 
var img=$(this);//img is the image clicked
//append the img to the div
$('#div1').append(img); });

});
```

EDIT added comments